# How to send emails by laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, email, amazon-web-services, laravel-5

I use a function for send email, and this contains html for send.I searched for documentation and i try installed `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3|~6.0"`  and `"aws/aws-sdk-php": "~3.0"` and  this is my function:

```
function enviarCorreo(Request $request){
    $myArray =$request->get('htmls');
    $registers =json_decode($myArray,true);

    foreach ($registers as $value) {
        $client = SesClient::factory(array(
                'version'=> 'latest',
                'region' => 'us-east-1',
                'credentials' => [
        'key'    => 'something',
        'secret' => 'something',
    ]
        ));

    $request = array();
    $request['Source'] = "info@tenebit.com.co";
    $request['Destination']['ToAddresses'] =  array("sebastian.moncada@tenebit.com.co");
    $request['Message']['Subject']['Data'] = "Cambio Precio";
    $request['Message']['Body']['Text']['Data'] = "hola";

    $client->sendEmail($request);
    }
}
```

When i execute this function, i get error:

```
Error executing "SendEmail" on "https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
<Error>
<Type>Sender</Type>
<Code>SignatureDo (truncated...)
SignatureDoesNotMatch (client): The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

The Canonical String for this request should have been
'POST
/

aws-sdk-invocation-id:6e193a6cd1a8f79ff9431f8a578fd33c
aws-sdk-retry:0/0
host:email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
x-amz-date:20170323T234114Z

aws-sdk-invocation-id;aws-sdk-retry;host;x-amz-date
b4a0fc6dfb3b8b956012d7ea58727e0f2674c24ecec5ca7cc7aa58151169fc2e'

The String-to-Sign should have been
'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20170323T234114Z
20170323/us-east-1/ses/aws4_request
90bda171b5066152e79af1168f8a107aa8f1255f38d1fe261efb757173b0e81c'
- <ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
<Error>
<Type>Sender</Type>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

The Canonical String for this request should have been
'POST
/

aws-sdk-invocation-id:6e193a6cd1a8f79ff9431f8a578fd33c
aws-sdk-retry:0/0
host:email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
x-amz-date:20170323T234114Z

aws-sdk-invocation-id;aws-sdk-retry;host;x-amz-date
b4a0fc6dfb3b8b956012d7ea58727e0f2674c24ecec5ca7cc7aa58151169fc2e'

The String-to-Sign should have been
'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20170323T234114Z
20170323/us-east-1/ses/aws4_request
90bda171b5066152e79af1168f8a107aa8f1255f38d1fe261efb757173b0e81c'
</Message>
</Error>
<RequestId>3487b258-1022-11e7-b9c4-8fda0cb028e9</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

AND

```
ClientException in RequestException.php line 111:
Client error: `POST https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
<Error>
<Type>Sender</Type>
<Code>SignatureDo (truncated...)
```

I appreciate your answers on how to solve it.

Comment: What is your SMTP configuration? What are you using to send the email??? I think problem with the credentials that you are using to send email.

Comment: SMTP configuration? is in .env?